# Creating an iframe or div that ignores page load

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to build an audio player for a website. 
So what I want to do is load and external source into a div or iframe. Once this is loaded it should ignore all internal links and page loads. Don't think you can bypass browser refresh, but this doesn't matter. As long as switching pages in the website does not affect the iframe or div.

Some examples are:
https://soundcloud.com/kendrick-lamar-music

Or any other online player. The bar is not reloaded on page switches.

Comment: Search about Single Page Applications, URL hashes, and learn something of javascript. Then try something by yourself. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please step first to [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)